# Set navigation parameter on goBack in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I have two screens A and B.

When i navigate from Screen A to Screen B I have passed Parameter `"onGoBack":false`.

On B Screen I have setParameter `"onGoBack"` as `true` Which is not working. On go back from Screen B I always receiving `"onGoBack"` parameter as `false` only.

Please help to solved this problem.

How can I received updated parameter value on go back.

Below the code I have used to set parameter on Go back from screen B

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.props.navigation.setParams({onGoBack: true});
        console.log('Updated Go Back Value: '+this.props.navigation.state.params.onGoBack);
        this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", () => {
                this.props.navigation.goBack();
                return true;
        });
    }
```

Comment: can you share a working expo snack so that i can check there

Comment: What's your motive? Can you tell what are you trying to achieve..

Answer (score 0):

You can get the navigation state params whenever a screen is mounted so try this:

```
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';

    render() {
            return (
              <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <NavigationEvents
                  onWillFocus={() => {
                    // Do your things here
                  }}
                />
              </View>
            );
          }
```

Or else,
You can send the params when you're navigating from screen A to screen B:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('screenB', { onGoBack: false });
```

So screen A is already mounted on Stack, so you can use the navigate function to send params. Here, the navigate function will act as goBack(); it won't push a new screen in the stack

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('screenA', { onGoBack: true });
```